# DDMS Source / Extending DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, command-line-interface, ddms, android-source

Anyone know where to find DDMS source code?  I want to extend its functionality.  Or is there a CLI for this tool instead of the eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 3):

The full sources for DDMS can be found in the [git repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/jb-mr1.1-release/ddms/).  DDMS can be used as a stand-alone SWT app, or integrated with the Eclipse plugin.  The common code is factored out into a couple of libraries.

**Update:**
Link updated for JellyBean MR 1.1.  The sources went elsewhere in JellyBean MR 2.

Comment: Updated the link with pointer into the new repository on the jb-mr1.1 branch.  The sources went elsewhere in jb-mr2.

Answer (score 2):

ddmslib is the java library that powers DDMS. Source is [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.android.ddmlib/ddmlib/r16)

Comment: No, there is no source of DDMS there, only the compiled version.

Comment: Yes there is look on the left hand side there is a tree navigation to the source directories

Answer (score 0):

The actual source of DDMS is in the Android source itself.

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/
```

sources are in: `ddmlib/`